# How to install pandas on a continuous integration server like bamboo with permission denied errors

Tags: python, bash, pandas, continuous-integration, bamboo

Hi I am unable to install pandas on a remote CI server like Atlassian Bamboo, where I am getting a permission denied error.

I am using virtualenv

Here is my bash script

```
# setup
virtualenv validate_ordercart
chmod u+x validate_ordercart/bin/activate
source validate_ordercart/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My requirements.txt file:

```
gdata==2.0.18
numpy==1.9.1
pandas==0.15.2
pipeables==0.1.29
PyGreSQL==4.1.1
python-dateutil==2.4.0
pytz==2014.10
six==1.9.0
xmlrunner==1.7.7
```

[View Log of the output here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2670838/DQ-VAL-JOB1-3.log)

Answer (score 1):

try replacing the last part with

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

or maybe try

```
sudo <path to script>
```

first.

Comment: `sudo` also gets me access denied and generally sudo isn't advised hence I am using the virtual environment